# job status stocks in pending (laravel horizon and vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, queue, horizon

i use `laravel 10` and   `vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq`

Suppose we have **two servers**, in each of one **Laravel Horizon** is serving a queue that the name of the queues are difference in each server. The producer dispatches a job, but the job is executed in the consumer who serves this queue . the producer enters the job correctly into the queue in RabbitMQ and the consumer also executes the job correctly. But the job remains pending in the laravel horizon of the producer server.I expect that the job in the producer or consumer will change to the completed state in the horizon.
i tried this with redis and it's working perfectly.but when i change the connection to rabbit this issue will happen.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.